# Is is possible to get visa for France in one week in India?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, france, applications

I am from India and visiting France on 12th May 2016 and I have applied for visa but there no slots available on this month. I have got a slot on 5th May 2016 and I know it will take 10-15 days to process visa.

My question - Is is possible to get visa in one week? if not what should I do to get visa asap?

Comment: You can ask the VFS if they offer a premium Schengen service.

Comment: thanks @GayotFow , Yes VFS provide premium service :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a premium service provided by VFS called "Premium Service Lounge".

I have got an appointment on same date by this facility. It is really great service by VFS and everything will be done very easily.

The Premium Lounge Service includes:

1. Separate lounge with personalized service by dedicated staff
2. Refreshments
3. Faster submission of applications at the visa application center
4. Courier return of passport
5. SMS alert on the status of your application
6. Photocopying and photo booth service for your documents

Important note: Your visa application will be processed and decided by the French Consulate in Bangalore, Use of the Premium Service Lounge does not affect the processing time of your application.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question, and reads a lot like paid marketing.

Comment: @CMaster I have taken the service and now im done with the visa processing and there is no other way to get the appointment so easily.

Comment: So does the premium service let you get an earlier appontment (and hence have your visa processed in time)? If so, please put that in your answer - right now it isn't clear how this solves your problem.

Comment: oh im really sorry for that. I totally forget to add that. Thank man @CMaster  :)

Comment: OK, but did you get your visa in one week at the end of the day?

Comment: This answers the "get an appointment" part of the question, but definitely not the "get a visa in one week" question. Also, the premium service is not available in all VFS locations, as far as I understand it. Including information about the additional cost for the premium service, and well as a link to the appropriate page, would probably be helpful to people in the same situation.